# Reverse List Either Printing only first variable or with -1 values

Tags: python, reverse

This code I am using will only print from the original list of [1,2,3]

**[2,1,0]**

---

```
def make_reversed_list(original_list):
    new_list = []
    length = len(original_list)
    l = length

    for value in original_list:
      if value >= 0:
          l = l - 1
          new_list.append(l)
   
    return new_list
```

---

Or if I change the code and remove the line so it reads and prints **[3,3,3]**

---

```
def make_reversed_list(original_list):
    new_list = []
    length = len(original_list)
    l = length

    for value in original_list:
      if value >= 0:
          new_list.append(l)
   
    return new_list
```

---

How can I change the code to reverse the original_list without using [::-1] or the Python reversed function?

Comment: Why would you even want to do that?

Comment: @gribvirus74 I need to for a class but I am stumped as why I cannot get the results I need.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are going the hard way, but here's one way to do it:

```py
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = []
>>> for value in x:
        y.insert(0, value)
>>> y
[3, 2, 1]
```